# What is a ''prototype party''?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Source: http://www.commarts.com/column/prototype-party

I am not sure what do they mean by prototype party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A party where you show people prototypes, in this case, art that isn't finished yet. I think that was fairly well explained by the article itself. What is a prototype party? A prototype party is literally what they described.

Prototype: Definition from Merriam-Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prototype)

Definition of prototype
1:  an original model on which something is patterned :  archetype

2:  an individual that exhibits the essential features of a later type

3:  a standard or typical example

4:  a first full-scale and usually functional form of a new type or design of a construction (as an airplane)

Comment: So you're showing people art that isn't finished yet?

Comment: Look up the dictionary definition for "prototype". You can prototype anything, products, software, art. A prototype party is just showing people prototypes.

Comment: I don't understand, do they mean exhibition or art that isn't finished yet?

Comment: It is an informal social gathering. A party. They invite their friends to show them the art projects they are working on. They are "prototypes" because they are not finished.